# Color force and nuclear force

Tags: nuclear-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force

What are color and nuclear force? Are they sub forces for the total force of the atom or the color force is a constituent factor for the nuclear force?

Comment: What is a "sub-force"? That's not physics terminology, and the strong interaction/force *is* the color force. I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: There is no "color force" . As the answer says the elementary particles which have a color charge will react to the strong force. The nuclear force is a spill over force of the strong force, the same  way that the Van der Waals force is a spill over force of the electromagnetic force.

Answer (score 5):

The [strong interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction) explains the characteristics and operation of the strong force, one of the four fundamental forces of nature (strong force, weak force, electromagnetism, gravity).  The strong force binds together quarks that compose protons, neutrons, and mesons.  Gluons are carriers of the strong force.

The [nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) is a residual manifestation of the strong force.  The nuclear force binds together protons and neutrons in the nucleus of the atom.  Mesons are carriers of the nuclear force.  Mesons, however, are composed of quarks and gluons, so the nuclear force is an effect of the strong force.  Sometimes the nuclear force is called a residual strong force.  It explains the nucleon-nucleon interaction of protons, neutrons, and mesons.

[Color charge](http://www.phy.duke.edu/~kolena/modern/hansen.html) is a gauge theory that describes how quarks and antiquarks are bound together into nucleons by the strong force.  [Quantum chromodynamics](http://physics.info/qcd/) explains the interactions of color charge, just as [quantum electrodynamics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPDP_8X5Hug) explains the interactions of photons with electrically charged matter.

Answer (score 3):

The force responsible for the stability of the atoms and the nucleons is the Strong force. Just like electric charge is a value of how much a particle interact with the electromagnetic field, the color of a particle is a value of how much a particle interact with the Strong field.